# How to seperate file and directory names from a filesystem object returned as a JSON response?

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on ReactJS project in which I am simulating a mini filesystem. This is a sample response that I'm getting from server.

**Response**

```js
const response = {
  "file_a.js": "console.log('here')",
  "dir_b"    : {
    "something.txt": "Yada yada"
  },
  "dir_c": {
    "dir_d": {
      "file_f.txt": "This is some file"
    },
    "dir_g": {
      "file_h.cpp": "#include<stdio.h>",
      "dir_i"     : {
        "j.java": "prntln"
      },
    },
  },
  "dir_none": {},
  "dir_z"   : {
    "dir_x.arr" : "[ 1, 2, 3 ]",
    "select.sql": "SELECT * FROM USERS"
  }
}
```

### How can I seperate directory and file names like below to show a list of both of them on UI?

**Output**

```js
const directories = [
  "dir_b",
  "dir_c",
  "dir_c/dir_d",
  "dir_c/dir_g",
  "dir_c/dir_g/dir_i",
  "dir_none",
  "dir_z"
]

const files = [
  "file_a.js",
  "something.txt",
  "file_f.txt",
  "file_h.cpp",
  "j.java",
  "dir_x.arr",
  "select.sql"
]
```

What I already have tried

```js
const directories = []
const files       = []

Object.keys(response).forEach(path=>{
  if(typeof(response[path])==="string") files.push(path)
  else directories.push(path)
})

console.log(directories)
console.log(files)
```

**Output**

```js
[ "dir_b", "dir_c", "dir_none", "dir_z" ]
[ "file_a.js" ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't too far off, but you'd want the method to be recursive. If it comes across an object, it should append the directory to the list **and call itself**, passing the child as an argument.

```js
const response = { "file_a.js": "console.log('here')", "dir_b" : { "something.txt": "Yada yada" }, "dir_c": { "dir_d": { "file_f.txt": "This is some file" }, "dir_g": { "file_h.cpp": "#include<stdio.h>", "dir_i" : { "j.java": "prntln" }, }, }, "dir_none": {}, "dir_z" : { "dir_x.arr" : "[ 1, 2, 3 ]", "select.sql": "SELECT * FROM USERS" } }
const directories = []
const files       = []

function getFilesAndDirectories(obj, prefix = "") {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(path=>{
    if(typeof(obj[path])==="string") files.push(path)
    else {
      directories.push(prefix + path);
      getFilesAndDirectories(obj[path], prefix + path + "/");  //Call itself with child object
    }
  })
}

getFilesAndDirectories(response);

console.log(directories)
console.log(files)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const response = {
  "file_a.js": "console.log('here')",
  "dir_b": {
    "something.txt": "Yada yada"
  },
  "dir_c": {
    "dir_d": {
      "file_f.txt": "This is some file"
    },
    "dir_g": {
      "file_h.cpp": "#include<stdio.h>",
      "dir_i": {
        "j.java": "prntln"
      },
    },
  },
  "dir_none": {},
  "dir_z": {
    "dir_x.arr": "[ 1, 2, 3 ]",
    "select.sql": "SELECT * FROM USERS"
  }
}

const reduceFn = (a, [key, value]) => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    a.files.push(key);
  } else {
    const dir = (a.path ? (a.path + "/") : "") + key;
    a.dirs.push(dir);
    Object.entries(value).reduce(reduceFn, {...a, path: dir});
  }
  return a;
}

const result = Object.entries(response).reduce(reduceFn, {
  files: [],
  dirs: []
});

console.log(result);
```

This example uses recursion, it reduces the entries of each directory object and uses an accumulator property `path` to keep track of the depth (the directory structure).